# Why did Emily draw this at end of Hide and Seek?

Tags: plot-explanation, hide-and-seek

[Hide and Seek (2005)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0382077/) a mystery thriller starring Robert De Niro as Psychologist David Callaway and Dakota Fanning as his daughter Emily Callaway.

David moves with Emily to a new house in Woodland after his wife commits suicide. Emily is traumatized by this event and doesn't talk much. For whole movie her character is as if she's mentally ill and is hallucinating about an imaginary friend. Emily used to draw her imaginary friend Charlie on paper. Until it's revealed at the end that David is the one who is ill and has schizophrenia. He's the one who killed his wife and other characters during the movie. He is the one who turns into Charlie to play Hide and Seek with Emily.

But when David is killed at end by Famke Janseen's character Katherine, she takes Emily with her.

Emily draws following picture at the end. She's probably drawing Katherine and herself living a happy life. I am confused about who the other head is?

My question is was Emily really ill or is there any supernatural element in the movie that I missed?

[image]

Comment: It's answered in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hide_and_Seek_(2005_film)#Endings

Comment: @Tetsujin: May I know what's the reason for revealing spoilers in edit?

Comment: The movie is 17 years old. Anyone still avoiding spoilers on it after that length of time lives a very sheltered life, has been building an extraordinary amount of anticipation…. or never wanted to see it anyway. ;) . There is absolutely no need to spoiler anything over a year old.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Alright. Makes sense. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hide_and_Seek_(2005_film)#Endings) is suggesting Emily has a disorder

> Emily's drawing of herself with two heads suggests that she might also have dissociative identity disorder

[IMDB's Alternative endings](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0382077/faq/#fq0023815) also suggesting Emily has a disorder

> There are four alternate endings

> it is evident that Emily's bedroom is actually a hospital room in a psychiatric ward

Which also explains her behavior

> Why did Emily disfigure Amy's doll's face?

> third possibility is that Emily was displaying the pathological side of herself